# Can I use a nodeJS library in my react project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a project that I'm building using React Typescript. I have a react form that on submit I want update a fillable PDF using array values.

I ran into this library here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdffiller

Am i able to incorporate this into my react project? If so how?

Would I still use `import PDFfiller` or would I use `var`. If not, what would be my best option? I don't see any react libraries that does what I'm looking for.

Basically, I have a react form that user fills out which is a product invoice form. I have an existing fillable PDF in my project. On form submit I want to access the PDF and fill the form from the values in my array to create and return back a PDF with the information.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ReactJS with NodeJS and this is how :
On my NodeJS server I am running backend operations.
For my ReactJS to communicate with NodeJS, I am using WebSockets that are implemented on client side using Redux (using their store to make my WebSockets) available everywhere.

This is pretty much it, you will need to run them on two different ports but it is do-able.

Answer (score 0):

No, not on the frontend at least. This package relies on PDF Toolkit which is a native module.

Your alternatives are to find some browser-compatible library like pdf.js, or make a Node server to use this library in.

Comment: I see, thank you for that information. I had found this one here `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf` , but this one looks like it's limited to `creating` a PDF I want to use an existing PDF

Comment: You just want to render it? I believe you can use pdf.js

Comment: are you referring to this `https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/` ? I don't know if I need to render it. So when they submit the form, I was going to add a button that says download invoice. Which would then create that new PDF from an existing template PDF on the server. If that makes sense.

Comment: In that case it does sound like you'd need to run one of these Node libraries in a Node server. CRA itself can't be used to run arbitrary Node versions, but you can write one separate and use it with the start script in development.